# SSRS report runs in Report Builder but user can't open and edit dataset

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a client where their SSRS reports all run as expected from within the Report Manager and from Visual Studio/Report Builder on any machine.

When a report is in design view on any machine other than the server however, the datasets cannot be edited.  On trying to open the Query Designer to edit the SQL script, they are presented with this error:

> Unable to connect to data source '[Data source name]'.
>
> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the the server is not responding.

And yet, I can close this error and click `Test Connection` on the Shared Data Source with success and run the report in Report Builder without issue.  Credentials are explicitly entered, we are not using Windows Authentication.

This happens on every machine other than the server which has SSRS installed on regardless of who is logged in, including the account that has administrator privileges on the SSRS server.

What reasons could there be for the report able to connect and return data but, using the same credentials, not be able to connect to the data source to edit the dataset query?

Comment: Is the data source setup for `local` and not the specific SQL Server name?

Comment: @WEI_DBA  Nope, properly named in the Connection string.

Comment: Are the report data sources actually pointing to the shared data sources or are they configured separately?

Comment: @SMM Shared data source used throughout.  As I say, the reports will run on any machine, they just can't open the dataset query editor.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096796/6490059 help?

Comment: @SMM  "Changing the connection string to `Data Source=<server name>;Initial Catalog=<database name>`, instead of localhost, allowed Report Builder to work properly"  As I said, this is how our connection string is set up, with the server explicitly named.

Comment: There was a different resolution for someone else in the comments. It was the closest I could find to your problem. Sorry...I'm out of ideas :-)

Comment: @SMM  Ah yes, thanks.  I'll have a look into it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Report Designer design view connects directly to the data source or goes through the SSRS server. It might be that it connects directly. Anyway, does a UDL test on the client reveal anything? Can you connect direct to the SQL server from the client?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Yes, I can connect from machines where the report's Query Designer does not work, using both Windows Auth and the SQL Login used in the SSRS Report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the database hosted on the same physical server as SSRS?  If not, it sounds like a double hop authentication/delegation issue.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brushstrokes/2013/02/18/kerberos-authentication-in-reporting-services/

Basically, your authentication path looks like this:
workstation - report server - report datasource.

If you are running it directly on the server, the authentication path looks like this:
report server - report data source.

If the report server has not been authorized as a delegate for the data source, your credentials will not get passed.

When you test credentials, from the report server, it is checking as itself (no double-hop).  From your workstation, you are connecting directly from the designer to the datasource (no double-hop).

Comment: We are not using Windows Auth.  The Data Source has explicit credentials.

Comment: I think this is what the problem may be, as the users have full functionality when logged in as themselves on the server, just not on their own workstation.  It has been passed to others better versed in sys admin than myself so I'll accept this as the answer.  Thanks for your help :)